# How to disable the keyboard listener for a period of time?

Tags: python, pynput

Is there a way to disable the keyboard listener for a period of time ?

```
import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def on_press(key):
   time = 5
   print(f"Key pressed: {key}")
   return time

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

The problem I face is if I press rapidly a key 10 times it will display the message 10 times. I would like the script to disable the listener for 5sec for example and not print the message for any key during that time.

Comment: You can store the time elapsed since the last message and decide whether to display a new one based on that.

Comment: yes I have tried that, but with the listener always on you still end up with the same number of messages as the number of key pressed. I would like the script to not take into account the key pressed during that time.

Comment: No, you are in control of when to print and when not to print. You can look at the time elapsed and decide not to print if it's too low.